# (Java Minecraft 1.14.3) Instant mining item that can be taken advantage of if the item is switched quickly

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am in 1.14.3 and I'm trying to give the player an item that when held gives the player instant mining. `execute as @a[nbt={SelectedItem:{id:"minecraft:shears"}}] run effect give @s haste 1 127 true`  I am also using `execute as @a unless entity @s[nbt={SelectedItem:{id:"minecraft:shears"}}] run effect clear @s haste` to clear the haste effect when shears are not in their main hand. However, if the player switches over quickly to a different item in the inventory and mines with it, the haste effect is applied to the other item just long enough for it to be taken advantage off.  Is there a way around this?

Comment: You mean that people can also instant-mine for example stone and also get the drop if they used a pickaxe? If yes, that's probably a bug, the mining time should be updated instantly, because the server validates mining times. If it didn't, custom clients could instant-mine anything at any time.

Comment: Why don't you just enchant the shears with efficiency <some high humber> instead of using haste?

Comment: @pppery Because the mining must be instant when the player is using shears, even with blocks that are not meant for it to mine.  For example stone slabs.  High levels of efficiency only work for blocks that are meant for the specific tool to mine.

Comment: Did not realize efficiency worked that way, thanks.

Comment: @FabianRöling It's not an issue of the mining time.  The problem is that the haste effect carries over onto the other item (for example a pickaxe) just long enough for the pickaxe to break/swing.

Comment: @Hydra What is the issue then? That the pickaxe gets one durability point taken off? Because you're already mining instantly, switching to the pickaxe gives you no advantage.

Comment: @FabianRöling The player is in adventure mode. So there are some blocks that I would like to allow them to mine instantly and some I wouldn't. Switching to the pick gives them this advantage of being able to mine the block with the pickaxe, or any other tool for that matter, and destroy it without a mining time.

Comment: There is the `effect.digSpeed` attribute modifier, but I wasn't able to get it to work when I last tried.